# Rails and JavaScript: Can't add .erb extension

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, file-extension

I have a JavaScript file called users.js and it is in app/assets/javascripts/users.js. I have it load in a single page using

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
```

I was thinking of using some Ruby code in the JavaScript file, so I changed the filename to users.js.erb. But when I do, the file shows up in my SublimeText project view as users.js.erb.js, and when I run my Rails app, I get a 404 error saying users.js.js couldn't be found.

Help? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my perspective, this is not a rails problem, but a problem with the editor you use. Check the file information in finder with cmd-i and change it back to users.js.erb.

Comment: Oh, I didn't change the filename with the editor. I did it in the Finder. I just happened to see that's how SublimeText reported the name.

Comment: I did a little experiment independent of files/projects that were ever used or viewed in SublimeText and was still having the issue. For some reason, my Finder was adding the extra .js extension. When I change the file name via Cmd-i as you suggest, all is well.